# CoreMedia.CMTime

Tags: frameworks, time, xamarin.ios, avfoundation, seek

I want to use the method Seek of the class AVPlayer. But this method take a parameter CMTime.
Could anyone knows about this object.

In order to move the playback cursor to a given time.

Comment: I recommend to remove you "seek" label and put "iphone" or "iphone-sdk"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apple documentation contains information on the [CMTime struct](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html).

As I understand it, you set the "TimeScale" to a timescale suitable for the media (e.g. 44100 = 1/44100 sec - which might be suitable for a CD). Then the "Value" represents units of that timescale. So, a value of 88200 would be 2 secs.

```
CMTime cmTime = new CMTime();
cmTime.TimeScale = 44100;
cmTime.Value = 88200;
```

Isn't too clear though, I'll grant you.

Comment: Not It's very clear !! i have tested it this morning and it's work well !!! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

there are syntax errors in the code. it should be:

```
CMTime cmTime;
cmTime.timescale = 44100;
cmTime.value = 88200;
```

or just

```
CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMake(88200,44100);
```